# JPanel and Pop UP's, where to insert an instance of the pop up

Tags: java, swing, popup, jpanel

I'm making a game that I would like to have a popup screen with options once a certain action has been taken. I don't know where to put the instance of the popup jpanel in my code. I don't want it in the constructor of the main JPanel that's the games board and I tried to add it in the main method but that didn't seem to work. Advice?

```
public class GameBoard extends JPanel {

    public final int EARTH_ORBIT_RADIUS = 200;
    public final int BOARD_WIDTH = 800;
    public final int BOARD_HEIGHT = 600;
    public final int INITIAL_EARTH_X = 700;
    public final int INITIAL_EARTH_Y = 300;
    public final int INITIAL_DELAY = 100;
    public final int PERIOD_DELAY = 30;
    public final static int SUN_COORDINATE_X = 500;
    public final static int SUN_COORDINATE_Y = 300;
    public final int INITIAL_ASTEROID_X = 500;
    public final int INITIAL_ASTEROID_Y = 100;
    public final int INITIAL_SHIP_X = 500;
    public final int INITIAL_SHIP_Y = 500;

    public static int earth_x, earth_y;
    public static int asteroid_x, asteroid_y;
    public static int ship_x, ship_y;
    public int t = 0;
    public int ship_t = 0;
    public int keyheard = 0;
    public int[] earthcoordinates;
    public int[] asteroidcoordinates;
    public int[] shipcoordinates;

    public static boolean isCollision = false;

    Image earth;
    Image sun;
    Image asteroid;
    Image background;
    Image ship, shipL, shipR, shipU, shipD;

    Timer timer;

    GameBoard() {

        initGameBoard();

        loadImage();

        earth_x = INITIAL_EARTH_X;
        earth_y = INITIAL_EARTH_Y;

        asteroid_x = INITIAL_ASTEROID_X;
        asteroid_y = INITIAL_ASTEROID_Y;

        ship_x = INITIAL_SHIP_X;
        ship_y = INITIAL_SHIP_Y;

        timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new ScheduledTask(), INITIAL_DELAY,
                PERIOD_DELAY);
    }

    void initGameBoard(){

        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(BOARD_WIDTH, BOARD_HEIGHT));
        setDoubleBuffered(true);
        addKeyListener(new KeyListen());
        setFocusable(true);

    }

    void loadImage() {
        ImageIcon earth_image_icon = new ImageIcon("earth2.png");
        earth = earth_image_icon.getImage();

        ImageIcon sun_image_icon = new ImageIcon("sun.png");
        sun = sun_image_icon.getImage(); 

        ImageIcon asteroid_image_icon = new ImageIcon("asteroid.png");
        asteroid = asteroid_image_icon.getImage();

        ImageIcon bg_image_icon = new ImageIcon("bg_pr.png");
        background = bg_image_icon.getImage();

        ImageIcon ship_image_icon = new ImageIcon("ship.png");
        ship = ship_image_icon.getImage();

        ImageIcon shipL_image_icon = new ImageIcon("shipL.png");
        shipL = shipL_image_icon.getImage();

        ImageIcon shipR_image_icon = new ImageIcon("shipR.png");
        shipR = shipR_image_icon.getImage();

        ImageIcon shipU_image_icon = new ImageIcon("shipU.png");
        shipU = shipU_image_icon.getImage();

        ImageIcon shipD_image_icon = new ImageIcon("shipD.png");
        shipD = shipD_image_icon.getImage();


    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        drawBackground(g);
        drawEarth(g);
        drawSun(g);
        drawAsteroid(g);
        drawShip(g);

    }

    void drawEarth(Graphics g) {

        g.drawImage(earth, earth_x, earth_y, this);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
    }

    void drawSun(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(sun, SUN_COORDINATE_X, SUN_COORDINATE_Y, this);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
    }

    void drawAsteroid(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(asteroid, asteroid_x, asteroid_y, this);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
    }

    void drawBackground(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, null);
    }

    void drawShip(Graphics g){
        if(keyheard == 0 || isCollision == true){g.drawImage(ship,ship_x, ship_y, this);}
        else if(keyheard == 1){g.drawImage(shipL,ship_x, ship_y, this);}
        else if(keyheard == 2){g.drawImage(shipR,ship_x, ship_y, this);}
        else if(keyheard == 3){g.drawImage(shipU,ship_x, ship_y, this);}
        else if(keyheard == 4){g.drawImage(shipD,ship_x, ship_y, this);}

    }
    public class ScheduledTask extends TimerTask {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            OrbitCalculation oe = new OrbitCalculation();
            earthcoordinates = oe.earthOrbitCalculation(t);
            earth_x = earthcoordinates[0];
            earth_y = earthcoordinates[1];

            OrbitCalculation oa = new OrbitCalculation();
            asteroidcoordinates = oa.asteroidOrbitCalculation(t);
            asteroid_x = asteroidcoordinates[0];
            asteroid_y = asteroidcoordinates[1];

            OrbitCalculation os = new OrbitCalculation();
            shipcoordinates = os.shipOrbitCalculation(ship_t,keyheard, ship_x, ship_y);
            ship_x = shipcoordinates[0];
            ship_y = shipcoordinates[1];

            CollisionDetector c = new CollisionDetector();  

            if(c.whoCollision() == "asteroid"){
                ship_x = asteroid_x;
                ship_y = asteroid_y;

                isCollision = true;


            }
            else if(c.whoCollision() == "earth"){
                ship_x = earth_x;
                ship_y = earth_y;

                isCollision = true;
            }
            else{ isCollision = false;}

            //if(GameBo 

            t = t + 1;
            ship_t = ship_t + 1;


            repaint();
        }
    }

    public class KeyListen extends KeyAdapter {

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
            int key = e.getKeyCode();

            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
                keyheard = 1;
            }

            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
                keyheard = 2;
            }
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
                keyheard = 3;
            }
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
                keyheard = 4;
            }
        }
        /**public int[] lastTwoKeys(KeyEvent e){
            last_two_keys[1] = last_two_keys[0];
            last_two_keys[0] = keyheard;

            return last_two_keys;

        }*/

    }
}
```

Comment: What action would trigger the popup?

Comment: a Collision would trigger the popup. So the boolean isCollision = true; should trigger the popup

Comment: Okay, and what is this "popup"? Is it just a panel which overlays the main panel? A dialog? Some thing else?

Comment: The pop up will be a dialogue or text panel  or window (I'm new to programming so I'm not sure about the difference between those words) that's in the top right corner of the panel which holds the game board. The idea is that when the Collision event happens this other panel or window or whatever popup with some options of commands they can make in the game like "Mine Asteroid" or "Blow Up Asteroid" or whatnot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JOptionPane to create Popup. see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html
No need to declare this component in constructor.